# How to add custom validation in AngularJS for JQuery signature plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, canvas

I'm trying to create an input form in Angular that collects a persons name and their signature.  For the signature part, i'm using a JQuery plugin that uses a canvas for them to draw the signature.  I'm new at Angular and having trouble figuring out how to tie the canvas into my form validation.  When the user tries to submit the form, I want Angular to stop them if the canvas is blank (signature is missing).

To check if the canvas is blank, I can make this JQuery call which returns true or false:

```
$('#signature').signature('isEmpty');
```

The HTML I have so far is:

```
<form ng-controller="SignatureController" ng-submit="submit()">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="td-name" type="text" required placeholder="Enter Name Here" ng-model="drivername"><br>
            NAME - Please type here
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="td-signature" type="text" id="signature">
            <canvas width="1098" height="268"></canvas>
            </div><br>
            SIGNATURE - Please sign here
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" ng-disabled="dataLoading" value="Clear" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#signature').signature('clear');">
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="dataLoading" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

What would I need to add/change to make Angular mark the canvas as being required when $('#signature').signature('isEmpty') returns true?

Comment: The reference guide for the signature plugin is here:  http://keith-wood.name/signatureRef.html

Comment: I recommend using an angular plugin.  Mixing JQuery and angular should be avoided if possible.  Check out https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad